# Freestanding feet for a bookcase

Tags: furniture

I've bought a pair of bookcases that don't have feet. They will stand in front of a wall that has hydronic baseboard. I don't want to completely block off the baseboard. My plan is to have the bookcases stand on feet that I make from wooden blocks.

I was planning to just set the bookcases on the blocks without any glue or any top-plate + hanger bolts. I am expecting gravity to hold everything in place, but will this be unstable or dangerous?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am expecting gravity to hold everything in place

Under normal circumstances hat's a reasonable expectation, even before the bookcase is filled with books. In basic principle this is little different to vase stands, which can be used under even really big and/or really expensive vases...

> but will this be unstable or dangerous?

Stability is a matter for the accuracy of the feet you make and how they sit on the floor. Do this right and stability is guaranteed.

As for dangerous, this is sort of a judgement call. Obviously it would be better if the feet were fixed so the bookcase above couldn't move in relation to them, in the event of a hard knock for example, but realistically how likely is this given the location of the bookcases? And once weighted with books the amount of force needed to shift them (in the only directions they *can* move) would have to be considerable, while this is by no means impossible be realistic about how possible/likely that is in *your* home.

If in your home there are rambunctious kids, or large pets (a big dog, small pony, fat pig, giant murder kitty), you might want to reconsider the plan. Which leads to.....

**Why *not* fix the feet in place??**
From the description I don't see any reason why these feet can't be fixed in place. If the hesitation is based on the permanence of the installation you could just lightly screw them into place from the underside, the screws well sunk under the surface of the foot in deep countersinks or shallow counterbores.